# Simulated not using App simulated location because once declined notification

Tags: swift, xcode, location, mkmapview

I have mad ean app that requires the userlocation services on a map, i used the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` notification in plist. When testing the app i hit decline to the notification and now I am unable to use the users simulated location and a am left with an zoomed out normal map. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting > Privacy > Location > You App

Switch on location services in settings.